# Efficient MySQL search for 1 Million Rows

Tags: php, mysql, search, indexing

Currently I use a `FULLTEXT` index on my MySQL database and use the simply query

```
MATCH (movie) AGAINST("City of Gold")
```

This is doing the job for now and it is picking up the right row from the databse.

But now, I've run into problems when there is a term like ***Cidade de Deus* City Of God** which is a very close variation or for instance, **City of Gold DVDDrip**

My problem is, what is the best search algorithm that matches the right row, bases on the maximum closest match in the database.

**My Idea:**

My naive idea was that, is there any inbuilt function or algorithm that matches the maximum number of words which match with the database and return a result.

I've come across Sphinx, but I was unsure if it solves the above problem or is it a hard task for it too?

Thanks

Comment: Probably nothing "off the shelf" will do quite what you want.

Comment: That quite strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There different algorithm to match for fuzzy searching like levenshtein. You can get the implementation of the algorithm from link below. It will return the distance a search phrase is from search item so on the bases of distance you can return the result.

https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/levenshtein-and-levenshtein_ratio-functions-for-mysql/

Comment: I'll have a look at it. It's funny there isn't anything of this sort already.

Comment: It's quite a good function. I've a small question. Is the MATCH or levenstein function more efficient while selecting rows?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but it has couple of loops to calculates distance for each row is it might not be efficient. For such scenario elastic search are good, you can have more verbose full text search.